# LESS-Gulp concatenation, how to not repeat variables import?

Tags: javascript, node.js, less, gulp, concatenation

Here is my gulpfile config, it lessify, concat into a single .css, remove comments, minify everything, and is outputted. Also very important : a sourcemap file is produced.

```
gulp.task('less', function() {
  return gulp.src(src)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(sort({
        asc: false
      }))
      .pipe(less())
      .pipe(concat('responsive.css'))
      .pipe(stripCssComments())
      .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
});
```

Let's say I have 5 .less files.

a.less, b.less, c.less, d.less, variables.less

Each less file (except variables.less) has @import 'variables.less', otherwise the compilation will not work.

In the final css file, the content of variables.less is repeated 5 times, obviously, because I imported it in each file.

How can I keep my sourcemapping without repeating the variables 5 times in the built .css ?

Comment: Either concatenate them *before* compiling or simply create an [explicit Less file](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/386c0bdbc71ea4d7b00d) representing the project (in both cases these less files content should not conflict of course).

Comment: I'm sorry but how does the sourcemap works then ? Because If I only call a master file which import everything itself, the sourcemap will not work because it will have only 1 file to parse

Comment: "the sourcemap will not work because it will have only 1 file to parse" - no, sourcemaps contain exact mapping to the original file/line, it absolutely does not matter if it was the master file itself or one imported there.

Comment: well it seem not, maybe I did a mistake. Here is my new function : `gulp.task('less', function() {
  return gulp.src('master.less')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(less())
      .pipe(concat('responsive.css'))
      .pipe(stripCssComments())
      .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
});` in master.less I only imported the others files. Now when I check on dev tools, the sourcemap is always referring to responsive.css and not a.css, b.css, etc

Comment: wow actually it works when I don't write the sourcemap in another file... what gives

Comment: Well, note that sourcemap is generatd by the Less compiler itself (i.e. inside `gulp-less`.) I.e. don't get misled by separate `.pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))` line, that one only saves the generated sourcemap to a file. Now notice that everything you put after `less()` task may screw the generated source map (for example if `stripCssComments` do remove the whole commented line - the original sourcemap is no longer valid and that task should regenerate new sourcemap using prev. one. That applies to *every* task after `less`. So watch there carefully).

Comment: For instance (as an example of "watch there carefully") does not `minifyCSS` task remove comments on its own so that `stripCssComments` is redundant actually?. Etc. Technically that one of the reasons to separate "development/production" (aka "debug/release") builds, so that the former has sourcemaps and whatever necessary debugging stuff, while the latter has all minification and all the blackjack with whatever (and does not need sourcemaps since they are just too hard to keep valid when you put too much tasks for the generated css files).

Comment: that's true, I modified my function to look like that : gulp.task(lessc, `function() {
    gulp.src(master)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest))
        .pipe(size({
            showFiles: true
        }))
        .pipe(stripCssComments())
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(minifyCSS())
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: min
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest))
        .pipe(size({
            showFiles: true
        }));
});`